# Setting up funnel URLs with regular expressions

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics to track my e-commerce checkout page. The URLs in the process are as follows:

1. /checkout/[order number]
2. /checkout/[order number]/your_details
3. /checkout/[order number]/review
4. /checkout/[order number]/complete

I've used the regular expression for the first page (/checkout/[order number]:

```
/checkout/\d+
```

That works fine, however the problem is I'm struggling to work out what the regular expression should be for the other pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should work

```
/checkout/\d+/your_details
/checkout/\d+/review
/checkout/\d+/complete
```

I got this from [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-issues-related-to-your-accounts-reports-and-data/h-HfziItm6k) which helpfully says

> To test this regular expression, go to the Top Content Report, scroll
>   to the bottom and enter the regular expression into the text box at
>   the bottom of the table.
>
> See if the filtered results match only pages that you want to consider
>   a goal.

Comment: I had tested the same regular expressions out in a Javascript regex tester but I wasn't getting a match for some reason. They are now working in the Top Content Report search so I should be good to go. Thanks.

Comment: I think the regular expressions that Analytics uses aren't the common ones used, and don't even correspond to the Google help pages on regular expressions. According to those \d would mean a literal d, not a decimal number. I think I need to ask a question about that...