# Google Analytics Regular Expressions Goals with Fragmented Urls

Tags: goals, regular-expression

I follow the suggestions of this post:

[Setting up funnel URLs with regular expressions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25886/setting-up-funnel-urls-with-regular-expressions)

and in https://regexr.com/ my sample works correctly:

The url in question would be like:

```
/cashier\/deposit\/success\/|amount_local=\d+
-------------------------------------------------------------
https://mysite.io/cashier/deposit/success/?a=amount_local=600
```

But when I try to verify the conversion goal in google analytics  I get 0%

Also if I tried:

```
/cashier\/deposit\/success\/|amount_local=100
-------------------------------------------------------------
https://mysite.io/cashier/deposit/success/?a=amount_local=100
```

I got the same results

My question is if Goals Regular expressions accept fragmented URL such as `/?parameter` ?